# How can i make a tree when onclick with jsf primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, tree

I  want to make a tree in jsf primefaces.What i want is that when i expand the treenode i want to take the treeNode and its all parameter(I need the id for query).Because i want it to work when i expanded a treenode.When i click to treenode i will make a query on database and bring the data.How is it possible ?

```
// for example:

  Fider fider=new Fider();
        //i dont know how i can take selected treenode's object(fiderUtil)'s id
        fider.setId(selectedfiderId);//?
        List<Fider> fiders=fiderrepo.find(fider);
        for(Fider fider:fiders )
        TreeNode treeNode=new DefaultTreeNode(new FiderUtil(fider.name(), fider.id()),selectedTreeNode);

       return treeNode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ajax expand event:

In your JSF page:

```
<p:tree id="tree" value="#{yourManagedBean.root}" var="node">
   <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{yourManagedBean.onNodeExpand}" />
   <p:treeNode>
       <h:outputText value="#{node.label}">
   </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

In your managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class YourManagedBean {

   private TreeNode root;

   public YourManagedBean() {

   }

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       root = loadTreeData(); // Fill your Tree with data
   }

   public void setRoot(TreeNode root) {
      this.root = root;
   }

   public TreeNode getRoot() {
      return root;
   }

   public void onNodeExpand(NodeExpandEvent event) {
      YourObject object = (YourObject) event.getTreeNode().getData();

      //Now make your database query 

   }

}
```

Comment: is it possible that onNodeExpand method return a TreeNode object?Because i want to bring the children when event.getTreeNode expands.

Comment: Yes i think the NodeExpandEvent returns the TreeNode with event.getTreeNode();

Comment: Well,how can i make the all treeNodes expandable by default ? @ Mahttias Schrebiér

Comment: I think there is an `expanded` attribute for each treeNode. If you set it on 'true' the node should be displayed expanded. I m not sure if there is a possibility to expandAll by Default. In worst case you have to iterate over your treeNodes or set the expanded attribute while initalizing the tree.

Comment: Did you make an update of the hole tree after setting the attribute? At the moment i am not able to test your problem, so i only can give you some suggestions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61681/discussion-between-mahttias-schrebier-and-aknkplnoglu).